# Wordpress download plugin with older file versions

Tags: plugins, wordpress, download

I'm looking for a way to offer downloads of files that change a lott. I like to have one file item in the list, but also offer the 'older' downloads. A good example is the way filehippo offers files. You can click CCleaner, but then your also offered the older versions. So if you need those, they are easily found. And old files don't clutter the general list.

http://filehippo.com/download_ccleaner

I couldn't find a plugin that advertises such a feature.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try [Wordpress Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/)?

I haven't used it much, but you can add categories to uploads to organize them. So for your problem, you could just make sure you use the File Manager after installing the plugin, and assign categories to each upload, then list groups of them you want to display. Make sure you put the version in the file name and you should be able to keep it organized.

[See more on their information page](http://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/docs/categories/). You can even make packages of downloads, etc. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps helps me download any version of the plugin

1. Go to plugin page on WordPress site ex: https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/
2. Open any plugin screenshot/image. It will open link straight to image ex: https://ps.w.org/file-manager-advanced/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=1821394
3. Change above URL and go to 1 folder before assets which will allow you to browse directory, go to tags folder (ex: https://ps.w.org/download-manager/tags/).
4. From there you will be able to see and download any version of the plugin.

Only works for plugins that are in WP store.